# How to add IEndpointsOperations interface using dependency injection in .net core 2.2

Tags: c#, azure-cdn, .net-core-2.2

I want to use `LoadContentAsync` method from `IEndpointOperations` interface with dependency injection available in .net core 2.2. Please share some code samples. I tried to add `AddSingleton`/`AddTransient` in `Startup.cs` and tried to use it in the controller constructor. But i get below error,

> Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: Cannot instantiate
>   implementation type
>   'Microsoft.Azure.Management.Cdn.IEndpointsOperations' for service type
>   'Microsoft.Azure.Management.Cdn.IEndpointsOperations'.

Exact method to be consumed is in below link,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.cdn.endpointsoperationsextensions.loadcontentasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Management_Cdn_EndpointsOperationsExtensions_LoadContentAsync_Microsoft_Azure_Management_Cdn_IEndpointsOperations_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_Collections_Generic_IList_System_String__System_Threading_CancellationToken_

Answer (score 0):

You need to let the system know the implementation class of an interface in the startup class. For example:

```
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IClass1, Class1>();

    }
```

May I know the implementation class of the interface IEndpointsOperations?

Comment: `EndpointsOperations` is the implementation class, but thats `internal` within `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Cdn` library.

Comment: This would be the problem. As it is an internal class, I suggest you get the instance from a CdnManagementClient  instance.